# Is there a short elegant way to write variable providing with exception?

Tags: java, coding-style, refactoring

So, I want to write these kind of things for my code, but there's too much code for one variable. How can I use modern Java for solving this problem shorter or cleaner? Moving it in the separate method doesn't solve the problem, because I still need to check the variable for null, which is wordy and adds extra method that used only once. It is possible to use Optionals here? Seems like `return` prevents this. Maybe there's the way for collapsing this thing into one for many variables like the `foo` described below? I don't know, just something to make it more readable and clean.

```
Foo foo;
try {
    foo = FooProvider.getFoo(...);
} catch (FooProvidingException e) {
    System.err.println("Foo exception: " + e.getMessage());
    return;
}
// use foo, maybe in another method (when foo is the field).
```

I know, this question may be opinionated, but any help would be a valid answer.

Sorry for my poor english and thanks in advance!

Comment: Optionals are meant for this - if I have time, I'll provide a simple example but you can probably find one online faster than I can type it up - i.e. https://www.baeldung.com/java-optional

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @blurfus, I know, how optionals work, but I don't know how to use them in this exact situation to make the code cleaner.

Comment: @Community, I just want to refactor this code too make it more readable and clean. In the normal circumstances we would just use `useFoo(FooProvider.getFoo())` as one-liner. But what I'm trying to show is handling exceptions while getting the value and stopping an excecution of the method using `return` statement. And this is just too much for one simple variable. I don't know how to explain it further.

Comment: It sounds like you want to do several things here: declare the variable, initialize it, catch exceptions thrown if previous step fails AND print the exception plus quit execution.  All of that in a one-liner and w/o using a helper method? I am afraid you might be making the code harder to read for the next fellow that comes to do maintenance on it.  Spending too much time on this might not be worth it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're asking is not very clear, so I don't know at which extent my answer will be meaningful.

If I understand well, you have fields of any type (`Foo`, `Bar`...) and you would like to instantiate them using whatever kind of provider you wish, which can throw an exception while providing.

So at first, I don't think that you should `return` if an exception is thrown by the provider, but rather re-throw it or handle it. Because if you had an exception while getting your `Foo` and so you actually don't have a `Foo`, why would you continue (or why wouldn't you try to handle it somehow)?

Now this said and assuming that re-throwing/handling is taken care of, then I would define a `ThrowingSupplier` functional interface:

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface ThrowingSupplier<T, E extends Exception> {
    T get() throws E;
}
```

... and then I would create a static method like this:

```
public static <T, E extends Exception> T provide(ThrowingSupplier<T, E> supplier) {
    try {
        return supplier.get();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        throw (E) e;
    }
}
```

So at that point, I would be simply calling this utility method every time that I want to execute such kind of operation:

```
Foo foo = provide(() -> FooProvider.getFoo(...)); //either creates a Foo, or prints and re-throw a FooProvidingException
Bar bar = provide(() -> BarProvider.getBar(...)); //either createa a Bar, or prints and re-throw a BarProvidingException
Integer myInt = provide(() -> 3);
String myStr = provide(() -> "hello");
//... and so on
```

But of course, at least once you'll have to extract the logic. Then it's all about extracting it in a way that it becomes generic and doesn't need to be repeated for each distinct type of object.

Answer (score 0):

I am also not sure what the end-goal here is but, as I understand it, here's a *simpler* version of achieving the following:

- Declaring and initializing the variable(s)
- Fetching values for it with a service provider
- Handling any exceptions thrown by this (or if the value is null) and exiting method
- Continuing execution if everything is as expected

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Foo foo1, foo2, foo3, foo4;
    try {
        foo1 = Optional.ofNullable(FooProvider.getFoo()).orElseThrow(new FooProviderException(1));
        foo2 = Optional.ofNullable(FooProvider.getFoo()).orElseThrow(new FooProviderException(2));
        foo3 = Optional.ofNullable(FooProvider.getFoo()).orElseThrow(new FooProviderException(3));
        foo4 = Optional.ofNullable(FooProvider.getFoo()).orElseThrow(new FooProviderException(4));

        // this works in or out of try/catch block
        foo1.printName();
        foo2.printName();
        foo3.printName();
        foo4.printName();

    } catch (FooProviderException fpe) {
        System.out.println("Exception: " + fpe);
        return;
    }

    // this works in or out of try/catch block
    foo1.printAgain();
    foo2.printAgain();
    foo3.printAgain();
    foo4.printAgain();
}
```